# Help with inner loop in Python method

Tags: python, methods, if-statement

I'm having trouble understanding why an inner loop in my method isn't producing the desired behavior I'm expecting and I'm hoping someone can help me understand the problem.

My method takes a series of arguments (`*args`) and if the argument is an integer I want to add dollar signs around the integer (eg. `$5$`).

```
def t_row(*args):
    columns = 5
    if len(args) == columns:
        count = 0
        for value in args: 
            if type(value) is int:
                value = ''.join(('$', str(value), '$'))
            count += 1
            if count < len(args):
                penult_args = args[:-1]
                line_prefix = [''.join((str(value), " & ")) for value in penult_args]
            elif count == len(args):
                line_suffix = [''.join((str(value), " \\\\", "\n"))]
        count += 1
        line_list = line_prefix + line_suffix 
        line = ''.join(item for item in line_list)
        return(line)
```

The above code is used like this:

```
>>> s = q.t_row('data1', 'data2', 3, 'data4', 5)  
>>> print s  
data1 & data2 & 3 & data4 & $5$ \\
```

Why don't I get dollar signs around the integer 3? How can I fix my code to correct this problem?

Comment: IMHO this code is Un-Pythonic: I would have your method require lists: `.t_row(value_list=[None,3,5], named_list=['data1', 'data2', 'data4'])` or event just return named values and pull them out of the `kwargs` like: `.t_row(data1=None, data2=3, data4=5)` `def t_row(self, *args, **kwargs):` `for param in kwargs:` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on this line:

```
            line_prefix = [''.join((str(value), " & ")) for value in penult_args]
```

you pull the values out of the original list (minus the last item), while on this line:

```
            value = ''.join(('$', str(value), '$'))
```

You added `$` but never stored the value back into the list.

The `5` only gets `$` because it's the last item, so you reference it directly in:

```
            line_suffix = [''.join((str(value), " \\\\", "\n"))]
```

A better way to do all this is:

```
def t_row(self, *args):
    if len(args) == self.columns:
        result = []
        for value in args:
            if isinstance(value, int):
                result.append('$%d$' % value)
            else:
                result.append(value)
        return ' $ '.join(result) + r' \\'
```

As a one-liner, it would be

```
t_row = lambda self, *args: (' $ '.join('$%d$' % 
          value if isinstance(value, int) else value for value in args) + r' \\' 
              if len(args) == self.columns else None)
```

but that's not actually a good idea.

Comment: Thanks agf. Your explanation is completely clear. For some reason I couldn't spot the error, but it's very clear now. I also greatly appreciate your solutions. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because in this line:

```
line_prefix = [''.join((str(value), " & ")) for value in penult_args]
```

You are overwriting `value` with the original (non-dollar-signed) value.

It works for the last argument only because the above line is not called for args[-1].

Use a different variable name for your loop.

(Python's scoping is only within functions and classes, `for` loops and `if` statements are not independently scoped.)